# Can BDD testing with Lettuce replace all other forms of testing in a project?

Tags: python, testing, bdd

I like Lettuce, and the feel of testing with it. Could I replace all the tests ( doctests/unit tests ) in a project with Lettuce features?

Comment: You're getting confused. In the title you only say 'replace **all** tests', but in the text you reduce that to 'replace all doctests/unit tests'. Do you have no integration or system tests? and are you asking about them too (as per Andy's answer) or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to disagree with Andy.

I do agree that the appropriate testing should be done at the appropriate time, and that unit tests (i.e. ones that do not interact with anything outside their unit) do not replace all other forms of testing.

But that doesn't necessarily mean that with the proper separation you cannot use a BDD framework (I too haven't used Lettuce) as the runner for your tests.

I too really like the fact that Gherkin syntax can be pushed back towards business experts, testers and sponsors as a means of capturing the process to follow, so I see no reason why one set of specifications can't be aimed at the Unit level, but another could be aimed at the system and regression levels.

Consider this (contrived and obviously nowhere near enough granular) example

- Given My test server is updated with last nights build
- When I run my regressionTestPack1
- Then my regression results should match the known results for
  regressionTestPack1

I am also not saying that this is appropriate in ever case. You should evaluate what benefit you get from this approach over leaving all your tests in different test running systems. In particular consider what the experience base is of the people performing the testing.

So if you are writing a small technical project, as the only the developer and you prefer this syntax, theres no reason not too. Just be very careful you still isolate your unit tests from your system tests from your regression tests.

If however you are part of a large team of devs, testers, business analysts, then your case will need to much stronger and is unlikely to actually be valid.

Answer (score 8):

In short, no.

I haven't used Lettuce, but your question applies equally to other BDD frameworks such as Cucumber.

This approach is considered bad practice since integration tests are slower to run and more work to maintain than unit tests.

Also, a big advantage of Gherkin syntax is that it's readable by non-technical stakeholders and it can focus on business rules, whereas unit tests generally deal with detailed implementation specifics at the class/function level not of particular interest to business-focused stakeholders.

There's sometimes an overlap between unit tests and integration/acceptance tests but in general you should aim to find an appropriate balance.

Answer (score 1):

It is a poor idea to use Gherkin/Lettuce for everything.

1) You should never do away with manual testing entirely. You might replace repetitive scripted testing, but you need to run the software past someone who can misunderstand or misuse it. Creative, destructive, human testing is important -- but the heavy lifting (90%+ of all testing) should be automated.

2) Another reason is covered alread: it runs slowly compared to unit tests. I find that the longer it takes to run a test, the less likely people are to run it frequently. You want it to be a non-decision to run the tests after each change, maybe 2 or 3 times every 5 minutes (yes, that fast!).

3) Personally, I think that writing unittests with sniffer or autonose in a different window gives me the very best environment for test-driving code. I don't know how to do that with lettuce.

4) Why switch out languages if you don't have to? Unittest is in python, and there are no fixtures or thunks of any sort to get to the code you're interested in testing. It works well with mocks and fakes. Gherkin is fun, but it's got more plumbing involved. The extra plumbing is great if you have non-programmers writing tests, but otherwise is just overhead.